# App crashes while trying to iterate through the ArrayList

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist

When i was trying to iterate through the arraylist of custom listview used for loop, my app suddenly crashed and when i tried to look at the logcat no error appeared. I've tried one by one finding the problem then i found out the problem is the part where i try to get the item value. can help me point out the problem?

This is part of my code in iterating/getting the arraylist value

```
 for(int i=0;i<=myAdapter.myItem.size();i++){
                    String name=tabl.getText().toString();
                    //this is the part that causes the crash
                    String answer=myAdapter.myItem.get(i).toString();

                    //mHelper.insertData(name,answer);
                    //temporary disable sql
                }
```

This is my subclass for the custom listview

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ArrayList myItem = new ArrayList();
    public MyAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 1; i < x+1; i++) {
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
            listItem.caption = "hahaha";
            myItem.add(i+".");
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return myItem.size(); }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position; }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position; }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null);
            holder.caption = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ItemCaption);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
        holder.caption.setText(myItem.get(position).toString());
        holder.caption.setId(position);
        //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
        holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    final int position = v.getId();
                    final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                    myItem.set(position, Caption.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
class ViewHolder { EditText caption;}
class ListItem { String caption;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
for(int i=0;i<=myAdapter.myItem.size();i++){
```

with:

```
for(int i=0; i < myAdapter.myItem.size(); i++) {
```

When you're using `<=`,  at the last iteration you're pointing to null. The condition should be just `i < myAdapter.myItem.size();`

Comment: this is correct but before asking a question here, try to debug that line by putting breakpoint and then pressing Debug on the top of AS